# Questions about Quantum Phase Estimation

Tags: quantum-algorithms

1. For https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/quantum-phase-estimation.html , what does it exactly mean by "***to recover the state |2<sup>n</sup>θ⟩, apply an inverse Fourier transform on the auxiliary register***" ?
2. Why QPE uses only two registers ?

[image: QPE]

Answer (score 1):

1. I find this updated textbook helpful for QPE examples: https://learn.qiskit.org/course/ch-algorithms/quantum-phase-estimation

From Qiskit's Documentation:

2. QPE (also sometimes abbreviated as PEA, for Phase Estimation Algorithm), has two quantum registers, control and target, where the control consists of several qubits initially put in uniform superposition, and the target a set of qubits prepared in an eigenstate (often a guess of the eigenstate) of the unitary operator of a quantum system. QPE then evolves the target under the control using dynamics on the unitary operator. The information of the corresponding eigenvalue is then ‘kicked-back’ into the phases of the control register, which can then be deconvoluted by an Inverse Quantum Fourier Transform (IQFT), and measured for read-out in binary decimal format...